# Is tagged hooks available in selenium "Python?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, python-behave

In Java we have a concept of tagged hooks like below:

```
@Before("@First")
public void beforeFirst(){
    System.out.println("This will run only before the First Scenario");
}
```

Likewise, is **tagged hooks** can be used in python behave?
If yes can you provide some examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can tag your scenario with @first and check this tag on the `before_scenario` function

> ```
> def before_scenario(context, scenario):
>    if "first" in scenario.tags:
>       """your code""""
> ```

Comment: Something like below?

def before_scenario(self, scenario, @first):

Comment: I edited the answer, check it. and tag your scenario with @first

Comment: Can we use this in before_all method?

Comment: yup, if you need to do it just once, like setting up your environment and stuff, then you don't need the @first tag at all